# “Matt was calling while we were having dinner” Is this correct?

Tags: past-tense, exam-questions, past-continuous

1. Matt ___ while we were having dinner.

A. called  B. was calling  C. has called

I chose B but answer is A.
Could you tell me why answer is A.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is (A).  There is no grammar mistake in (B) but it is unlikely to be used.

The verb "call" has a number of meanings, from "shout" to "guess", but the meaning here is probably "contact by telephone". If you understand this to mean  "Matt made contact with us by telephone..." then this is a single event that occurred at some time while we were eating.  So the simple past tense would be correct.

It you mean "Matt was making repeated attempts to contact someone" or "Matt was making repeated shouts for help" then "was calling" could be correct.  But such a sentence has a very odd meaning, and so is rejected in favour of (A)

Comment: Excellent answer. One could even make a case for C (Matt _has_ called while we were having dinner [on numerous occasions].